# Cambiar propiedad con JS en filtro

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, filtro

Tengo un sitio que debo modificar: http://kickads.mobi/sipea/index-test.html

Lo que necesito es algún código JS para que cuando se filtren los elementos, los de la segunda fila que están centrados se alineen a la izquierda, ya que tienen una propiedad `text align: center` y debería "deshabilitar" dicha propiedad, y cuando se borra el filtro clickeando sobre la opción "TODO", vuelvan a su posición original en el centro. Estos 3 elementos de la segunda fila están en otro div con la clase para centrarlos.
Si se fijan, al filtrar alguno de los elementos de la segunda fila, deja un espacio en blanco en su margen izquierdo. Eso es lo que estoy intentando quitar.

Les dejo el código del filtro, los elementos a filtrar y el CSS que estoy usando para la segunda fila:

```
            <div id="myBtnContainer">

             <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link" style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item activo" category="all">Todo</a>
                 </button>
                     <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="recipientes">Recipientes</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="pallet_piso">Pallets / Pisos</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="municipales">Contenedores Industriales / Municipales</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="cajones">Canastos / Cajones</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="menor_porte">Contenedores de Residuos de Menor Porte</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="bins">Bins</a>
                 </button>
                      <button id="rubros1" class="btn btn-link " style="color: white">
                   <a href="#" class="category_item" category="tambor_tanque">Tambores / Tanques</a>
                 </button>
     </div>

            <section class="products-list" id="desk">

            <div class="product-item" category="recipientes">
                <a href="recipientes.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/recipientes-1.jpg" alt="" > </a>
                <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Recipientes</a>
            </div>

            <div class="product-item" category="bins">
                <a href="bins.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/bins-1.jpg" alt="" > </a>
                <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Bins</a>
            </div>

            <div class="product-item" category="pallet_piso">
                <a href="pallets_pisos.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/palet-1.jpg" alt="" > </a>
                <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Pallets / Pisos</a>
            </div>

            <div class="product-item" category="municipales">
                <a href="industriales_municipales.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/cindustriales-1.jpg" alt="" > </a>
                <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Contenedores Industriales / Municipales</a>
            </div>

        <div class="row text-center col-md-12">
                    <div class="product-item" category="cajones">
                                    <a href="canastos_cajones.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/cajones-1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Canastos / Cajones</a>
                </div>

                <div class="product-item" category="menor_porte">
                                    <a href="menor_porte.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/menorporte-1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Contenedores de Menor Porte</a>
                </div>

                <div class="product-item" category="tambor_tanque">
                                    <a href="tambores_tanques.html"><img class="img-responsive figura" src="img/works/tambores-1.jpg" alt=""> </a>
                    <a href="#" class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Tambores / Tanques</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Y el CSS del div "text-center":

```
.row.text-center > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: @alanfcm perdón, como está un poco desordenado, no quise subirlo. Pero ya modifiqué mi pregunta e incluí el código

Comment: Deberias tambien incluir el codigo del filtrado.

Comment: @alanfcm Ahí lo volví a modificar. Espero que esté bien!